# How to efficiently match values from 2 series and add them to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file "qwi_ak_se_fa_gc_ns_op_u.csv" which contains a lot of observations of 80 variables. One of them is geography which is the county. Every county belongs to something called a Commuting Zone (CZ). Using a matching table given in "czmatcher.csv" I can assign a CZ to every county given in geography.

The code below shows my approach. It is simply going through every row and finding its CZ by going through the whole "czmatcher.csv" row and finding the right one. Then i proceed to just copy the values using .loc. The problem is, this took over 10 hours to run on a 0.5 GB file (2.5 million rows) which isn't that much and my intuition says this should be faster?
This picture illustrates the way the csv files look like. The idea would be to construct the "Wanted result (CZ)" column, name it CZ and add it to the dataframe.
[File example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZn2V.png)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("qwi_ak_se_fa_gc_ns_op_u.csv")

czm = pd.read_csv("czmatcher.csv")

sLength = len(data['geography'])

data['CZ']=0

#this is just to fill the first value

for j in range(0,len(czm)):

    if data.loc[0,'geography']==czm.loc[0,'FIPS']:

        data.loc[0,'CZ'] = czm.loc[0,'CZID']

#now fill the rest

for i in range(1,sLength):

    if data.loc[i,'geography']==data.loc[i-1,'geography']:

            data.loc[i,'CZ'] = data.loc[i-1,'CZ']

    else:
        for j in range(0,len(czm)):

            if data.loc[i,'geography']==czm.loc[j,'FIPS']:

                data.loc[i,'CZ'] = czm.loc[j,'CZID']
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.
Your problem could be easier to understand if you provide few first lines of your csv files.
In my mind, your problem could be solved faster by joining your 2 files. Take a look at pandas merge operations : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Hello. I added a screenshot which gives an idea of how the files look like. I am not sure how I could apply merging here since the two files are completely different in terms of size. I'll look into it though, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is a left merge on your dataframes,

```
data = pd.read_csv("qwi_ak_se_fa_gc_ns_op_u.csv")
czm = pd.read_csv("czmatcher.csv")
```

I assume that in both dataframes the column country is spelled the same,

```
data_final = data.merge(czm, how='left', on = 'country')
```

If it isn't spelled the same way you can rename your columns,

```
data.rename(columns:{col1:country}, inplace=True)
```

read the doc for further information https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it faster, but not reworking your whole solution I would recommend to use [Dask](https://dask.org/) DataFrames, to say it simple, Dask divides your reads your csv in chunks and processes each of them in parallel. After reading csv. you can use .compute method to get pandas df instead of Dask df.

This will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd #IMPROT DASK DATAFRAMES

# YOU NEED TO USE dd.read_csv instead of pd.read_csv

data = dd.read_csv("qwi_ak_se_fa_gc_ns_op_u.csv")
data = data.compute()
czm = dd.read_csv("czmatcher.csv")
czm = czm.compute()
sLength = len(data['geography'])
data['CZ']=0
#this is just to fill the first value
for j in range(0,len(czm)):
    if data.loc[0,'geography']==czm.loc[0,'FIPS']:
        data.loc[0,'CZ'] = czm.loc[0,'CZID']

#now fill the rest
for i in range(1,sLength):
    if data.loc[i,'geography']==data.loc[i-1,'geography']:
            data.loc[i,'CZ'] = data.loc[i-1,'CZ']
    else:
        for j in range(0,len(czm)):
            if data.loc[i,'geography']==czm.loc[j,'FIPS']:
                data.loc[i,'CZ'] = czm.loc[j,'CZID']
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. With this I get an error: 

  File "<ipython-input-270-56064dc7d8df>", line 14, in <module>
    if data.loc[0,'geography']==czm.loc[0,'FIPS']:

  File "C:\Users\Filip\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().